# Java 8 Lambdas: Mapping a Stream to type Integer and then calling sum() won't compile

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

I was playing around with Java8 lambda expressions. As an example I then tried to sum up the ages persons contained in a list:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person("FooBar", 12), new Person("BarFoo", 16));
        Integer sumOfAges = persons.stream().map(Person::getAge).sum();
        System.out.println("summedUpAges: " + sumOfAges);
    }

    private final String name;
    private final Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this snippet with the following java compiler:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0-ea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-lambda-night
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

I get the following compile error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sum()
  location: interface java.util.stream.Stream<java.lang.Integer>
```

But if I change the return value of the getAge() method from Integer to int, I get the expected result. But sometimes it is not possible or desired to change signatures on the fly. Is there any way to make this working when getAge() returns a Integer type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `reduce()` should work too - `map(Person::getAge).reduce(0, Integer::sum)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think they are changing the method

```
IntStream map(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)
```

to

```
IntStream mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)
```

then your

```
persons.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).sum()
```

will always work, whether `getAge()` returns `int` or `Integer`.

See this thread: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001480.html

BTW you can post your questions to lambda-dev mailing list, they'd like to hear real world experiences.

Answer (score 2):

They are not changing the methods, both of them are available where as **map**() is a generalized method that returns Stream, and they have separated the int, long, double Stream into separate method such as **mapToInt**(), **mapToLong**() and **mapToDouble**().

Yes, you can use reduce() method

**reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator< T > accumulator)**

Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using an associative accumulation function, and returns an Optional describing the reduced value, if any.

**How reduce() works**: suppose we have stream of int array and we apply the reduce function

> reduce(0, (l, r) -> l + r)

In a list of integers such as 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, the seed 0 is added to 1 and the result (1) is stored as the accumulated value, which then serves as the left-hand value in addition to serving as the next number in the stream (1+2). The result (3) is stored as the accumulated value and used in the next addition (3+3). The result (6) is stored and used in the next addition (6+4), and the result is used in the final addition (10+5), yielding the final result 15.

So you example would look like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Person {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person("FooBar", 12), new Person("BarFoo", 16));
        Stream<Integer> stream = persons.stream().map(x -> x.getAge());
        int sum = stream.reduce(0, (l, r) -> l + r);
        System.out.println(sum);

    }

    private final String name;
    private final Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add bayou.io answer, I prefer lambda expression instead of method reference.

```
persons.stream().mapToInt(x->x.getAge()).sum();
```